# File keeps getting a "Not Responding" error whenever I open a file

Tags: memory-management

I'm pretty new to Blender so I am not quite sure what is happening but whenever I open this specific file, the program crashes. I've looked it up and I've seen it could be a memory error but if it is I'm not even sure how to fix it. Is there anyway I can open this file and potentially lower its file size so I don't encounter this problem again? I am using Blender 2.82 currently

Comment: can you put the file in here so we can see if other people can open it and can you put how much memory your computer has in here to please.

Comment: You can use https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ to add the .blend to your question

Comment: I have 16 GB of RAM and I cannot upload the original file because it is over 300MB. However, I went back and amended some of the objects from my original file and deleted the ones that were severely raising the file size. I got it down to 19MB now but I wanted to ask, for mesh objects that I have been adding I have been turning the subdivision surface to 6 and by deleting the spheres that I did that to, it really lowered the file size. Was that the reason my file kept crashing or was it due to something else?